# KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES permission Violates rules GooglePlay?

Tags: android, google-play, kill-process

i had develop  an application contains `KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES` permission , my questions have i violated the rules of `GooglePlay`

`

Comment: I think you didn't, but you should read the google play rules any way if you want to publish apps there. I'm not sure if it is still not deprecated, and you still can kill background processes in latest Android versions...

Comment: i know is deprecated in Android 6.0.1 and above ,thanks for your reply